# Voltage variations with N Channel MOSFET and flyback diode

Tags: mosfet, diodes

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fncrtM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a circuit that uses an LM338K adjustable power regulator to supply 14V to a electromagnetic loop coil for producing a pulsed square wave signal under 500Hz.  The coil has approximately 10.5 ohms resistance and about 6.25 Henries.

The switching to generate the pulse is produced by a raspberry pi GPIO pin driving an N-Channel MOSFET (NTE2980).  I have a flyback diode across the coil outputs to kill the ringing in the square wave.

Here's the problem I'm experiencing and I'm hoping someone can explain this observation and offer an option on how to correct it:

With the flyback diode in place, I get a variation of voltage coming out of the regulator (when the MOSFET is off).  That voltage measures around 16.2 V and the regulator becomes only nominally adjustable.  When I remove the flyback diode, the voltage returns to the 14V the regulator is set at.  Of course, the diode is also protecting the MOSFET, which if the diode is removed, gets hot fairly quickly (~20 seconds).

So, why would the flyback diode be causing the power fluctuation and what is the right solution to fix it?

Here's a text representation of the circuit:

- 14V positive supply connected to one side of the
  electromagnetic loop.
- Other side of the loop connected to the drain
  of the mosfet
- MOSFET source connected to ground.
- PI GPIO driving gate of MOSFET
- Diode placed directly across the loop coil terminals.

Comment: I'm thinking I might need a diode between the R2 wiper on the voltage regulator and ground.  My suspicion is that some of the current flowing out of the MOSFET might be throwing off the voltage reference on the LM338K resistor pair.

Comment: Do you have any capacitors? Please show on the schematic if so :)

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? The waveforms at the regulator output and MOSFET drain would be of interest. (Unrelated to your issue) What's the intended purpose of R4? The MOSFET gate is getting rather marginal drive voltage as it is (2.2V nominal for a MOSFET characterized at 4V).

Comment: No capacitors in this circuit.  It's exactly as indicated in the schematic.  R4 is a pulldown resistor for the Raspberry Pi gpio.  The GPIO outputs 3.3 volts when ON and on system startup, is floating around 2 volts.  The purpose of R3 and R4 are to pull the floating voltage down below the MOSFET ON threshold, thus eliminating an ON state for the MOSFET.

I know what you're talking about with the marginal drive voltage.  This particular MOSFET is a logic level one with a VGS(th) of 1 to 2 volts.

Comment: The waveform of the regulator and MOSFET drain show a nice square wave with just a slight negative drop on the trailing end of the square wave.  The big question is, why would that voltage be changing only when D1 is present in the circuit?

Comment: And just to clarify, R4 is a trimmer which I can adjust until I see the optimal shutoff of the MOSFET when the GPIO is in a floating state, but optimal output from the circuit too when the MOSFET is ON.  When I connect a ammeter between + supply and the Loop Coil, I can adjust R4 to produce the peak amp output, which corresponds closely to the point when the floating voltage is pulled below VGS(th).

Comment: I'll second what @awjlogan said about capacitors.  You should have input and output caps on the regulator and possibly additional decoupling at the top of the coil.  The only reason I can think of for the symptoms you describe are something going unstable (but you say a scope shows clean waveforms) and poor layout/grounding/construction.

Comment: If the GPIO is floating a 10K resistor from gate to ground should be fine to keep the FET off, and it's large enough so the GPIO can drive it when on.  I still don't understand the purpose of a variable R4.  You certainly don't want LESS drive on the FET.  If you want to control the current in the coil, use PWM, don't try to run the FET in the linear region.

Comment: Thanks John.  I did have a 10uF electrolytic cap across the coil at one time.  Its effects were nominal in the circuit. The 338k regulator is a 5amp output variety and with the coil resistance I have, it should be drawing about 1.3 amp.  I'll consider throwing a few caps back in, though the data sheet indicates they should not be necessary.  As far as the GPIO resistors, I added that configuration with the voltage divider setup after finding the MOSFET wouldn't shut off while the GPIO was floating.  I had tried values up to 22k.  The divider config seems to work well.  I'll try the caps again.

Comment: Caps may not be required by the linear regulators datasheet, but it doesn't mean that they are not good practice.  If your FET doesn't shut off with a floating GPIO and a 10K pull-down then maybe that's a clue that something else is wrong with your circuit.  You shouldn't need a 2K variable resistor to tune the pull-down if the GPIO is tri-state.

Comment: Thanks John. That sounds like reasonable advice.  I'll do some tinkering and report back what I find.

Comment: There comes a time when every man must temporarily turn in his Man-Card and take the beating he well deserves.

I put in the caps as John recommended to no avail.  However I did notice as I was scoping around that my coil output was reading nearly 18 volts across its terminals.  Checked the regulator, it was set correctly.

Went back and looked at the PCB drawing and noted a critical error.  I had a trace between the Regulator output connected directly to the 18V supply.  Yes, I said that correctly.  Regulator OUTPUT to SUPPLY INPUT.

Comment: That's what I get for trying to work until the wee hours of the morning.

Took that trace out, took the caps out, works perfectly.  Nice square wave, very little ripple, properly regulated, and no components get hot.

So essentially, if I had put it on the PCB the way I sketched it above, all would have been right with the world.

<<Turns in Man-Card>>

Comment: With no caps, where would the energy stored in the inductor go when it free-wheels?

Comment: Winny, not quite sure what you are asking.  The purpose of the diode is simply to reduce ringing in the inductor.  Of course it only reduces half the ringing wave, but for my purposes, it works well.  The critical function of this transmitter wave circuit is that the falling edge of the square wave be as immediate as possible.  It does produce a slight negative anomaly on the falling edge of the wave, but it's within an acceptable limit.  But for the sake of discussion, where would you recommend a cap to drain the charge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCB error caused the problem. Circuit works fine as drawn above.